# Localize "Sign in" and "Sign up" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, globalization

Is it possible to provide different **submit button** values depending on the current controller/view?

So having 2 views:

```
=# app/views/devise/sessions.new.html.haml
%h2 Sign in
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean
  = f.button :submit
```

and

```
=# app/views/registrations/new.html.haml
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = devise_error_messages!
  = f.input :first_name
  = f.input :last_name
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :password_confirmation
  = f.button :submit
```

I want to show **Sign in** on the first and **Sign up** on the 2nd view **without changing the view** itself.

FYI, Localising `submit` buttons is possible via:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      user:
        create: 'Sign up'
```

But unfortunately I can't see how to distinguish between the views above (or controllers) to give different messages for submit buttons.

So the **question** is how the `en.yml` file should look like to achieve that?

Comment: That's unfortunate :( Want to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Probably there is a way... but it's super heavy IMHO https://github.com/railsdog/deface

Comment: Wow. That is really heavy lifting... But definitely an option. It looks like it works with `ERB` only. But thanks, just another option.

Comment: There is an HAML branch. I don't know how it works because I strongly dislike HAML :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I18n provides standard way to distinguish between controllers:

```
en:
  users:
    registrations:
      new:
        create: "Sign up"
    sessions:
      new:
        create: "Sign in"
```

Your forms require a little change (the same for sessions and registrations):

```
  = f.button :submit, t('.create')
```

Unfortunately I didn't find a more easy way to do it without that little `t('.create')` with simple_form.

Look at that `.` (dot) before create. Rails will scope `create` by controller name. In our case users/sessions_controller became 'users.sessions', the same for registrations.

Comment: I know this and mentioned it in the question. Not sure how your answer actually answers since @lucapette pointed it out in the comment as well.

Comment: But I guess your answer is probably the easiest and simplest thing you can go with :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that devise is localised, and that the community made locale files for a good bunch of them. I can't tell you from the top of my head, but they might solve this problem, or give you a hint about how to achieve that. Check out the wiki on devise github page.

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of things localised in Devise except this :)